# Error in sending Authentication Token in GET request using Axios in React to a Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, axios, get, authorization, bearer-token

I am trying to make a simple GET request to my Nodejs Server for which the user needs to be logged in. So I have to send the Auth Token too. This is how I am doing it.

```
const fetchReminder = async () => {
    console.log(typeof localStorage.getItem("token"));
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/user/reminders", {
      header: {
         Authorization: `Bearer ${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')}`, 
        
    }});
    setReminder(response);
    console.log(response);
  };
```

My token is similar to eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2NDdjMjU4MTI5NTYzMGFlZTY5MDU2N2IiLCJuYW1lIjoiU2NhcmxldFdpdGNoIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg1ODg2OTkzLCJleHAiOjE2ODY3NTA5OTN9.ZaStQhH6m0M_h27tPf20mvfeB9ImkFdweLWHDnL_ORK

To this, it is giving me,
Error 401 Unauthorized.
How do I resolve this?

Important: This route works fine with Postman